# AngularJs in not working in Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs, razor

**I am working in asp.net mvc4 with Razor View. I am using angularJs with it. But in partial view angularJs is not working.**

**Here is my view code:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Requisition", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "RequisitionForm", ng_app = "" }))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="divSection">
        <div class="divBox divSectionLeftLeft">
            <label>Product</label>
        </div>
        <div class="divBox divSectionLeftRight">
            <input type="text" id="ProductName" name="ProductName" ng-model="newItem.ProductName" />
        </div>

        <div class="divBox divSectionRightLeft">
            <label>Quantity</label>
        </div>
        <div class="divBox divSectionRightRight">
            <input type="text" id="Quantity" name="Quantity" ng-model="newItem.Quantity" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divClear">
    </div>

    <div class="ContainerRowButton">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini" ng-click="items.push(newItem); newItem={}">Add Req-Detail</button>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 800px; height: 160px; overflow-y: scroll">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="RequisitionDetailsTbl" ng-init="items=[]">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Product
                    </th>
                    <th>Quantity
                    </th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tr ng-hide="items.length">
                <td colspan="3">No Requisition Added Yet. . .</td>
            </tr>

            <tbody ng-repeat="item in items">
                <tr>
                    <td>{{item.ProductName}}
                    </td>
                    <td>{{item.Quantity | number:2}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" id="delReqDetail" ng-click="items.splice($index, 1);" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini">Delete</button>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
}
```

**My _Layout is like this:**

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery, ~/bundles/jqueryui, ~/bundles/others")
```

**Here "~/bundles/others" contains the angular.js.**

**I am not getting any error in firebug console. What wrong am I doing?**

**One more thing I am showing the partialview in popup window. The code Works fine if I don't use it in popup window.**

Comment: Just a quick check to ensure js are loaded. In you Bundle configuration file add this line "bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();" at the beginning of "RegisterBundles" function

Comment: I've checked in firebug, all the scripts are loaded.

Comment: So you are running with optimization set to false, this is the only way to check if angular is loaded place this {{1+1}} let say after @Html.ValidationSummary(true) and tell me what you see

Comment: I am showing the partialview in popup window. The code Works fine if I don't use it in popup window. Can you please suggest me anything about this?

Comment: Inline popup or external window?

Comment: I am using bootstrap popup.

Comment: Where is your controller?

Comment: You mean angular controller? Actually I've posted partial code. In my original code I've used ng-controller and I wrote the controller code in the same page into script tag. I didn't use different script file for controller.

If any how I can run the code snippet that I've posted in the popup window, I think I'll able to run the whole code.

Comment: Make a sample on plunker or jsfiddle, because from your code there is no way to tell whats wrong

Comment: Looks like this partial view is loaded with AJAX or something, dynamically anyways. And you forgot to tell Angular to parse this new content which wasn't part of the initial DOM when the page loaded.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov can you please show be an example. That might solve my problem.

Comment: @raisul, example of what? You're gonna have to first explain your scenario and show your code before talking about *examples*.